# RAILS - tacking on a message when form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I can't seem to figure this out or find a solution to this anywhere...which is crazy to me since i feel like its pretty common and simple

I want to add a little message that my client will see when the user sends them a request through the form and then it goes to an external API where they can see created tickets.

so right now my client sees

```
 John Doe
```

but i want them to see

```
 Web inquiry from John Doe
```

So i need to send the "Web inquiry from" part through the form

i've tried to interpolate it in the form

```
 = f.text_field "Web inquiry from #{:subject}"
```

that didnt work

i've tried to add a value (not the way i want to go but i tried it anyway)

```
 = f.text_field :subject, value: "Web inquiry from #{f.object.subject}"
```

that did not work either

i've tried to place it in the model

```
 def post_tickets(params)
   client.subject = "Hello from, " + client.subject
 end
```

I'm new to rails so if you could be specific as possible that would be helpful...please dont say just do it in the controller.....thank you in advanced

here is my form

```
= form_for(:contacts, url: contacts_path) do |f|
= f.error_messages
= f.label :subject, "Name"
%span{style: 'color: red'} *
= f.text_field :subject, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
%br
%br    
= f.label "Email"
%span{style: 'color: red'} *
%br    
= f.email_field :email, class: "text_field width_100_percent"
%br
%br
= f.label "Question(s), and/or feedback"
%span{style: 'color: red'} *
%br
= f.text_area :description, class: "text_field width_100_percent", style: 'height: 100px;'
%br
%br
= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-warning'
```

here is my controller

```
 class Website::ContactsController < Website::WebsiteApplicationController
   def new
     @contacts = Form.new
   end

   def create
     @contacts = Form.new(params[:contacts])
     @contacts.post_tickets(params[:contacts])
     if @contacts.valid?
       flash[:success] = "Message sent! Thank you for conacting us."
       redirect_to new_contact_path
     else
       flash[:alert] = "Please fill in the required fields"
       render action: 'new'
     end
   end
 end
```

here is my model

```
 class Form
   include ActiveModel::Validations
   include ActiveModel::Conversion
   include ActiveModel::Translation
   extend  ActiveModel::Naming

   attr_accessor :config, :client, :subject, :email, :custom_field_phone_number_28445, 
            :custom_field_name_28445, :custom_field_company_28445, :description, 
            :custom_field

    validates_presence_of :subject, :message => '^Please enter your name'
    validates_presence_of :description, :message => '^Question(s), and/or feedback can not be blank'
    validates :email, presence: true  
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each do |name, value|
        @attributes = attributes
      end

      self.config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/fresh_desk.yml")[Rails.env]
  self.client = Freshdesk.new(config[:url], config[:api_key], config[:password])
    end

    def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
      @attributes[key]
    end

    def post_tickets(params)
      client.post_tickets(params)
    end

    def persisted?
      false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def post_tickets(params)
  # prepend to the params['subject'] just before posting
  client.post_tickets "Web enquiry from #{params['subject']}"
end
```

Comment: i get a can't convert nil into String

Comment: i did have it to subject

Comment: I have modified `post_tickets` method to include the wordings. see if it works

Comment: You should not `+` a var to a string without checking if the var is `nil?`.  Use interpolation